# Left alignement FLEX

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I hope someone could help me please. I would like to align the blocks to left, I've used flex with "justify-between" to have spaces between automatically but the problem is that the last row made 2 blocks with one space huge space with nothinG.

[print SCREEN OF THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR8mB.png)

MY css:

```
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 20px;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

My code:

```
{# LPs listing #}
<ul>
  {% for item in module.resources_block %}
  <li>
    <div class="lp-block">
      <div class="content-description">  
        <div>
         <span class="keyword">{% inline_text field="tag" value="{{ item.tag }}" %}</span>
        <h3>
          {% set href = item.link_field.url.href %}
          {% if item.link_field.url.type is equalto "EMAIL_ADDRESS" %}
          {% set href = "mailto:" + href %}
          {% endif %}
          <a href="{{ href }}"
             {% if item.link_field.open_in_new_tab %}target="_blank"{% endif %}
             {% if item.link_field.rel %}rel="{{ item.link_field.rel }}"{% endif %}
             >
            {% inline_text field="title" value="{{ item.title }}" %}
          </a>
        </h3>
        {% inline_text field="description" value="{{ item.description }}" %}       
        </div>
        <div>
          {% set href = item.link_field.url.href %}
          {% if item.link_field.url.type is equalto "EMAIL_ADDRESS" %}
          {% set href = "mailto:" + href %}
          {% endif %}
          <a class="{% if item.cta_text %}ghost-cta{% endif %}" href="{{ href }}"
             {% if item.link_field.open_in_new_tab %}target="_blank"{% endif %}
             {% if item.link_field.rel %}rel="{{ item.link_field.rel }}"{% endif %}
             >
            {% inline_text field="cta_text" value="{{ item.cta_text }}" %}
          </a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{# End LPs listing #}
```

How to do it with flex? but keeping the automatic space-between and the spaces (margin) between.

Comment: `justify-content:flex-start` should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `justify-content` & `margin` and add `gap:20px` this should fix the issue

```
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap:20px
```

or just use `justify-content:flex-start` instead of `justify-content:space-between`